# Strip names after linking a static library

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries, debug-symbols, toolchain

In a static library project for iOS 6, some functions in a .c file is referenced by others, and therefore are considered global symbols, but should not be exposed to the user of this library.

How can I `strip` these function names out? Also, how can I hide those obj file names as well so that nobody could see the .o names in `nm` output?

I have tried to enable/set:

- Deployment Postprocessing
- Strip Debug Symbols During Copy
- Strip Linked Product
- Strip Stype: either 'Non-Global Symbols' or 'Debugging symbols'
- Use Separate Strip

**EDIT:**

I see that there is another Build Setting item 'Additional Strip Flags'.
By adding in it a flag `-R /path/to/symbol_list_file`, `strip` command would remove symbols indicated in the file, or `-s /path/to/exported_symbol_list_file -u` to indicate interfaces and leaving undefined symbols at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't.  A static library is simply a collection of object files and the object files within the static library have no special privileges over those *using* the static library.

You can obviously `strip` the final binary.

If you must hide symbols then they need to be `static`, which forces you to use fewer implementations files to allow the symbol to be shared, which is inconvenient.

Comment: What can I do to hide implementation details/linkage info like the paths of .o files from 3rd party clients of my static lib? Could it be obfuscated, at least in Release builds?

Comment: @ZhangChn Well the only way I can think of is to put all the implementation (or at least the stuff you want to protect) into a single `.o` file within the library.  That's a bit rubbish, but please tell me what you are trying to hide and why?