# Solved: Xcode archive errors with "Undefined symbols for architecture arm64" when internal framework

Tags: objective-c, xcode, frameworks, archive, missing-symbols

Posting some learnings after much searching for:

- Xcode app deploys fine in debug mode to iOS device, but archive fails with: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
- Archiving an app with an internal framework
- Using Swift in a framework with Objective-C

**The situation:** I was refactoring an iOS app and added an audio unit target. To share the main parts of the app I created a private framework. The refactor went well and the app deployed to the devices just fine. But archiving was failing, it seemed Xcode was stripping symbols out.

The "arm64" is a bit misleading. It's also not a strip on copy problem (see this post on [a static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18528460/strip-names-after-linking-a-static-library)). Changing any of the settings did not work, e.g. removing symbols in the "Copy Phase Strip", "Remove Swift symbols". Builds would fail with the linking error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC13_SOMETHING_31_SomeOtherClassName", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SomeObjCFile.o
      ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Did you get answer to this? Facing exact same issue when I changed my frameworks from static to dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution: add `public` to framework classes you want to expose to Obj-C.**

It turns out release mode is stricter. Add `public` to framework classes and methods you want to expose to Objective-C. Also found a raywenderlich.com article, ["Creating a Framework for iOS"](https://www.raywenderlich.com/17753301-creating-a-framework-for-ios#toc-anchor-008), that explains things.